# cli curl to php curl for uploading file

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to set up the php curl library call to take:

```
curl --location \
     --header "authorization: LOW $accesskey:$secret" \
     --upload-file /home/samuel/public_html/intro-to-k.pdf \
     http://s3.us.archive.org/sam-s3-test-08/demo-intro-to-k.pdf
```

(this is for Internet archive's api: http://archive.org/help/abouts3.txt )

This is currently on a Windows 7 dev box, but will be moving to Ubuntu

I have tried:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('authorization: LOW XXXX:XXXXX'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://s3.us.archive.org/a_tested_working_dir/the_file_ane_and_ext' );
    $post_array = array(
        "upload-file"=>file_get_contents($absolute_path_to_my_file)
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
```

Error:  MalformedPOSTRequestThe body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.bucket must be in dns hostnameXXXXXXXXXX

I'm able to substitute my own values into the cli curl statement & upload without issue; I just can't seem to get the php curl correct

TIA!

---

A --libcurl dump produced:

```
CURLcode ret;
CURL *hnd = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)64d);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "http://s3.us.archive.org/jeffs_test_1301_librivox/test-francesbaird3.mp3");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS, "c:/Users/JMadsen/_ssh/known_hosts");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);
ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
```

I think it might be ssl verify, but just tried setting to false & no change

Comment: Does your `curl` command work?

Comment: it's strange - I've added CURLOPT_UPLOAD, CURLOPT_INFILE, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE and it seems to have worked once, but I can't get ti to work again. Pretty sure at this point it is end-of-day tiredness, so going to take a breather and look at it again

Thanks so far - your --libcurl showed me the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post field initialization for uploading file is wrong. You dont need to pass contents of file. Just pass the path of the file with `@` prefix.

```
$post_array = array(
    "upload-file"=>'@'. $absolute_path_to_my_file
);
```

According to the `--libcurl` dump **add** the following options too.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.21.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) libcurl/7.21.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_KNOWNHOSTS, "c:/Users/JMadsen/_ssh/known_hosts");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50);
```

Comment: sorry, that is just psuedo-code

anywhere you see "mycode" or "myfile" type stuff, assume I'm really using hard-coded & working value. I'll try to make it clearer with an edit

Comment: I just tried "upload-file"=>'@'. "/absolute/path/to/my/file", but get the same error

Comment: @jmadsen okay. I have removed that part too. Did you try the solution?

Comment: If your command line works, just append `--libcurl code.c`. It'll dump a c file `code.c`. There you'll see all the options that command uses. You can use the same options for PHP.

Comment: are you sure "--libcurl" ? command not found, and can't find any reference to that googling

Comment: @jmadsen I am more than sure. `--libcurl is not a command`. I said you to **append** it to the curl command you used.

Comment: sorry, must have fat-fingered somethinh - have th efile, looking now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23076/discussion-between-jmadsen-and-shiplu-mokadd-im)